# CloudFlare SSL (htaccess) redirects to index.php on laravel

Tags: laravel, web, https

I'm using laravel and I have a problem redirecting my clients to `https` and `www`.
for example:

from: http://domain.com/abc/def

to: https://www.domain.com/abc/def

this is my `.htaccess` code:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https

# First rewrite to HTTPS:A
# Don't put www. here. If it is already there it will be included, if not
# the subsequent rule will catch it.
RewriteRule .* https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

# Now, rewrite any request to the wrong domain to use www.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule .* https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

It's already redirects to `https://www.` but it always redirects to `index.php` file.

for example, instead of redirecting to `https://www.domain.com/abc` it redirects to `https://www.domain.com/index.php`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I've fixed it. I just needed to put this code before laravel's code:

```
# Redirect Trailing Slashes...
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

so now the full htaccess is:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
# First rewrite to HTTPS:A
# Don't put www. here. If it is already there it will be included, if not
# the subsequent rule will catch it.
RewriteRule .* https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
# Now, rewrite any request to the wrong domain to use www.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule .* https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

# Redirect Trailing Slashes...
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```